# Lazarus: StringReplace ineffective when working with files (unicode issue)

Tags: string, replace, lazarus, fpc, delphi

I'm using Lazarus to build a simple app that builds Outlook signatures based on a template. The idea is to extract the template (a ZIP file), and replace variables within the files it contains.

For example, I may want to replace `{fullname}` with the name provided by the user.

I am currently using the implementation below, but it seems to be ineffective. The file is read and written to, but it appears the replacements are not being made. I have tested to see if my implementation of `TFileStream` is not correct, but using `WriteAnsiString` to append dummy text onto the end of the output file works.

Please would you kindly have a look at my code below and let me know what I may have done wrong, or if there are any better alternatives to `StringReplace`? I am aware that one can use `TStringList` - however, doing so breaks line endings. As memos and rich edits use `TStringList`, using those won't help either.

**Update:**

I have seen [this](/questions/16135373/delphi-search-and-replace-code-not-working), but using `AnsiString` makes no difference. If I'm not mistaken, FPC uses it by default anyway, instead of `UnicodeString`.

**Update 2:**

Indeed, `AnsiString` is the default. Using a unicode string (which makes the replacements work) adds `?` to the beginning and end of the file. Why would it do that?

---

```pascal
function multiStringReplace(const s: string; search, replace : array of string; flags : tReplaceFlags): string;
var c : cardinal;
begin
    assert(length(search) = length(replace), 'Array lengths differ.');
    result := s;
    for c := low(search) to high(search) do
        result := stringReplace(result, search[c], replace[c], flags);
end;
```

```pascal
procedure fileReplaceString(const fileName: string; search, replace: array of string);
var
    fs: tFileStream;
    s: string;
begin
    fs := tFileStream.create(fileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
        setLength(s, fs.size);
        fs.readBuffer(s[1], fs.size);
    finally
        fs.free();
    end;
    s := multiStringReplace(s, search, replace, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    fs := tFileStream.create(fileName, fmOpenWrite);
    try
        fs.writeBuffer(s[1], length(s));
    finally
        fs.free();
    end;
end;
```

**Usage:**

```pascal
fileReplaceString(currentFile, ['{fullname}'], ['Full Name']);
```

Comment: Is your template file contains UTF16 text? If yes - try to recode it to UTF8 (native encoding for Lazarus).

Comment: It appears that the `.txt` file Outlook generates is indeed UTF-16LE (whilst the `.htm` file is Windows-1252). How can I chck the encoding of the file in question and convert accordingly?

Comment: About text transcoding you can read [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multiplatform_Programming_Guide#Text_encoding) for example. However for my little test file in UTF-16LE function `GuessEncoding` returns `utf8` for some unknown reason. Using hardcoded source encoding works fine: `ShowMessage(ConvertEncoding(s, EncodingUCS2LE, EncodingUTF8));` Do not forget to use `LConvEncoding` unit.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed looks very useful - shall give it a try tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @Abelisto - that indeed does the trick, thank you. Just used `s := convertEncoding(s, guessEncoding(s), encodingUTF8);` before replacement, and now all works as expected. And Outlook doesn't seem to disagree.

Comment: You can to post your corrected code piece as answer and accept it to mark your question as answered.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Abelisto's comment above, it appears the issue is due to the fact that Outlook saves the three files it creates with different encodings. To get around it, I simply used `convertEncoding` and `guessEncoding` from `lconvencoding`, as below:

```pascal
uses
    lconvencoding;
```

```pascal
// Read string
s := convertEncoding(
    multiStringReplace(s, search, replace, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]),
    guessEncoding(s), encodingAnsi
);
// Write modified and converted string back to file
```

`encodingAnsi` appears to be the best conversion, at least in my case. Converting to UTF8 (with or without BOM) caused a bit of a headache with certain characters, specifically EmDash or EnDash.